# Locally defined alias not working inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, echo, alias

I'm trying to define an alias `alias echod='echo -e "\033[0;31m"'` (it prints in red the text) inside a script so it's not needed to have the .bashrc imported.

But as soon as I use it I get an error:

```
./.AVVIO.sh: riga 23: echod: command not found
./.AVVIO.sh: riga 24: echod: command not found
```

my code is (row numbers are in square braces):

```bash
#.AVVIO.sh

[10]   DEBUG_COLOR='\033[0;31'



[19]   alias echod='echo -e \"${DEBUG_COLOR}\"'



[23]   echod "\$# = [$#]"
[24]   echod "\$1 = [$1]"
```

I expect the code printed in red (first parameter and parameter number)

Comment: bash [manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html): "Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the *expand_aliases* shell option is set using *shopt*."

Comment: also in the bash manual: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."

Answer (score 3):

Use a function.  eg:

```
#!/bin/sh

DEBUG_COLOR=$(tput setaf 1)
RESET=$(tput setaf 9)

echod() { printf "%s%s%s\n" "$DEBUG_COLOR" "$*" "$RESET"; }

echod "\$# = [$#]"
echod "\$1 = [$1]"
```